# Magento 2.3.4: Why doesn't Magento admin configuration take any effect on the `fax` field?

Tags: event-observer, frontend, magento2.3.4, place-order, default.xml

The option for fax under `Store->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration->Name and Address options` was set to `NO` right from the beginning of the installation of Magento 2. It is strange to see the fax field on the storefront where it shouldn't be. Is this a bug or am I supposed to have done something? Also, if I remove the `fax` field via default.xml then the `Place Order` button becomes inactive leaving nothing in the log files for us to debug. Can anyone say if there is a fix? Does it have anything to do with the event handlers that are being made use of in our Magento site?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Show Fax to No does definitely work after clearing cache.